# How to reload PartialView being displayed in a SideBar?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, sidebar

I have a `SideBar` in which gets launched from the left side of the screen when a `Button` is clicked. It loads the page `SideView.cshtml` page in it. On clicking `Submit`, I want the `SideBar` to stay opened and the page `SideView.cshtml` to be refreshed to show the changes. How can I do that?

I am keeping the `SideBar` open and active in the following way, but I am unsure on how to refresh it keeping the `SideBar` active at the same time.

```
    $.post({
        url: "/PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrdersSideView",
        data: { ... },
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {            
            $("sideViewBar").addClass("active");
            $("sideViewDetails").addClass("active toggled");
        },
        error: function (xhr, text, error) {
            alert('Error: ' + error);

        }

    });
```

Comment: How sidebar & sideview page layout looks like? Sounds you need to return a partial view in controller action and use `html()` to render it from successful AJAX callback.

Comment: I am calling my `SideBar` in the following way: `<a onclick="OpenSideBar(orderId);" data-ma-action="sidebar-open" data-ma-target="#details" class="..."></a> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For keeping open `SideBar`, you can use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of `$.post` like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrdersSideView",
    data: {...},
    success: function(data) {
        $("sideViewBar").addClass("active");
        $("sideViewDetails").addClass("active toggled");
    },
    error: function(xhr, text, error) {
        alert('Error: ' + error);    
    }
});
```

`$.ajax` prevents from refreshing page and closing your `SideBar` by performing an asynchronous request.